# Exec Function, saving Methods/Classes/Variables -> Method

Tags: python, python-requests, python-module, python-exec

I'm writing a library for creating smaller python modules. I am not sure if I should be using compile() instead of exec(), it currently execute the files(any basic code in the global scope is executed) but not stored as methods in the Function where it can be accessed later by a different file *ETC...*.
*It loads the python files as strings*

### Basic Usage Example

```py
from bagel import webImport

MyFile = WebImport("https://WhereFileIsLoaded.py")
# OR Feature Not Added Yet

MyModule = WebImport("https://WhereModuleIsLoaded.zip")
```

**Here is the Code**

```py
import requests
from functools import wraps


# Thank you stack overflow
def withself(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwds):
        return f(f, *args, **kwds)
    return wrapper


def webImport( URL: str):
    data = requests.get(URL).text
    
    


    @withself
    def returnFunc(self):
        funcs = {}
        exec(data, {'__builtins__':__builtins__}, funcs)
        print("Executed Data")
        setattr(self, "funcs", funcs)
        return self
    
    # Function Object
    FUNC = returnFunc()

    for func in FUNC.funcs.items():
            # Can go through multipe because self.funcs 
            if not hasattr(FUNC.funcs, str(func[0])):
                print(func[0])
                # Setting the Atribute of this class -> The FUNCTION with the body of the functiion  
                setattr(FUNC, str(func[0]), FUNC.funcs[func])
                # exec(f"FUNC.{func}")

    return FUNC
```

And here is the Console Output, I am using Python IDLE To test this.

```py
from webImport import webImport
web = webImport("https://pastebin.com/raw/xDJxwMri")
```

#### Console Output

[Console Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UYf2.png)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this line,

```py
setattr(FUNC, str(func[0]), FUNC.funcs[func])
```

Use This

```py
setattr(FUNC, str(func[0]), FUNC.funcs.get(func[0]))
```